# Ngrx change delay() interval after X number of minutes

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

> Hi, I am new to ngrx. What I am trying to achieve is have a method that repeats to execute an action to get status updates for items in an observable until the observable is empty. For the first 
>   minute I want to repeat the execution of the action lets say every 5 seconds and then slow it down to say 10 seconds. But it seems like I can not update the duration of the delay during the process. 
>   I will appreciate any suggestions on how it could be achieved.

```js
        this.myObservable$
            .pipe(
                delay(pollDelay),
                takeUntil(this._destroyed),
                map(items => {
                    console.warn(new Date());
                    if(initialPollingUntil < new Date()){
                        pollDelay = 10000;
                    }                    
                    if (items.length !== 0) {
                        this._store.dispatch(getStatus({ payload: { items: items} }));
                    } else {
                        this._destroyed.next(true);
                    }                    
                }),
                repeat()
            )
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here. What's `myObservable$`? Emitting once or kept open? Are you trying to have some polling that happens every 5s, get an observable value and  dispatch an action based on that? What's repeat for in this case?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create an `interval` of 1 minute and then apply a custom emission delay, for example:

```js
const source$ = interval(1000 * 60).pipe(
  take(2),
  // for every minute we want to increase the delay by 5 seconds
  switchMap(minute => interval((minute + 1) * 5 * 1000)),
  tap(minute => console.log(`Retrying ${new Date()}`))
);

source$.subscribe();
```

Full example can be found in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b2mv8t?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it's hard to guess what you want to do.
Would be great to see more info about it.

Below you can find an updated version of your code that executes checks every 5 seconds and once `initialPollingUntil` is in past it executes checks every 10 seconds.

Simply replace your code with this one.

```js
const tick = new BehaviorSubject(initialPollingUntil);
tick.pipe(
    switchMap(date => this.myObservable$.pipe(
        first(),
        delay(date < new Date() ? 10000 : 500),
    )),
    tap(items => {
        if (items.length !== 0) {
            this._store.dispatch(getStatus({ payload: { items } }));
        } else {
            this._destroyed.next(true);
        }
    }),
    tap(() => tick.next(tick.value)),
    // takeUntil(this._destroyed), // <- uncomment if this._destroyed should kill all subscriptions.
).subscribe();
```